# Using Console_CommandLine

Tags: php, pyrus

I have installed Console_CommandLine using pyrus:

```
php pyrus.phar install pear/Console_CommandLine
```

the directory where Console_CommandLine was installed has the next structure:
`(/A_PATH/lib/`)

```
lib/
├── cache
├── data
├── docs
├── downloads
├── php
└── tests
```

I've tried the next:  (`/A_PATH/demo.php`)

```
<?php
    require_once 'lib/Console_CommandLine/php/Console/CommandLine.php';
    ...
 ?>
```

but I have the next error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(Console/CommandLine/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /A_PATH/lib/Console_CommandLine/php/Console/CommandLine.php on line 32
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Console/CommandLine/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /A_PATH/lib/Console_CommandLine/php/Console/CommandLine.php on line 32
```

How can I use the CommandLine.php file for my personal project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your include path. PEAR packages rely on it being set correctly, so that their includes work properly:

```
set_include_path('.:/A_PATH/lib/php/');
```

You can also set that in your `php.ini`, which is how it's done most times.

A howto to setup your include path can be found in the PEAR 1 manual: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php